# HttpServlet lifecycle and serialization

Tags: serialization, servlets, lifecycle, init

I wonder if the init method of a HttpServlet is called after deserialization.

I don't know if any container ever serializes a servlet but it implements the Serializable interface so there is a possibility to do that.

The JavaDoc for the init method points out: "Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being placed into service."

Is a deserialization equals "placed into service" ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a servlet is never serialized. It's a singleton, and is typically completely stateless. I wouldn't see the point in serializing it. Anyway, regerdless whether it's newly instantiated or deserialized, the init method must be called when it's placed into service, so a servlet container would be in violation of the spec if it placed the servlet into service without initializing it.

Answer (score 5):

While I have never actually dealt with a container that would swap out a servlet by serializing it, and I honestly can't really imagine when a modern container would do this, but I have always understood that `init()` is called exactly once for the servlet in its lifecycle, so, it would *not* be called again on deserialization. As with anything `Serializable` you would need to write special handling by implementing `readFields()`.

Comment: Ok here it starts to become complicated. The GenericServlet (which intro. the Serializable interface in the hierarchy) only says: "Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being placed into service." The other point: "The servlet container calls the <code>init</code> method exactly once after instantiating the servlet." is said in the JavaDoc of the Servlet interface which is not serializable.

Comment: Another point is that the ServletConfig which is passed to the init method is stored in a transient field...